# Replace ceramic capacitor with electrolytic capacitor in DC RC filter

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design

I got this circuit, but I do not have the correct value of the ceramic capacitor C1. Is it possible to use the electrolytic capacitor in that circuit without problems?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of the electrolytic capacitor and what is the required debounce and activation time for the switch?

Comment: Are you saying that you *have* a 100 nF electrolytic capacitor, but *don't have* a 100 nF ceramic capacitor?

Comment: Seems more  likely  to me that you might have a 100uF electrolytic capacitor (1000x too big) but that's just a guess. It's unusual to find electrolytic caps much under 1uF.

Comment: Unfortunately yes I check it many times. I got the capacitor kits (500Pcs/lot 0.1UF-1000UF 24Values Aluminum Electrolytic Capacitors 16-50V) you can google it. I know that are strange values :( I need this RC to filter the interference from the stepper motor, I got the wires so close that interference with MCU and false trigger the endstop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would look like it, yes, as C1 will reliably be biased in one direction, and even strong ringing from the switch will have a very hard time reversing the voltage over 100 nF.

Note that 200 Ω + 3.3 kΩ is relatively strong resistors. MCU inputs have much smaller leakage currents than what would dictate these values. Try 4.7 kΩ + 68 kΩ instead, together with 4.7 nF instead of 100 nF, and save a lot of power while getting nearly the same frequency response from your circuit.